# Java/Javascript bring browser window containing applet to foreground

Tags: java, javascript, browser, window, focus

Is there a way to pull a browser window to the foreground/focus from a Java applet alert window?  I have an applet in a html page that brings up an alert with a button in it.  When the button is pressed, I want the original browser window to pop up from wherever it is (minimized, covered, etc.)  I believe there is a way to connect Java to Javascript to do this, but I don't know Javascript.

Here is the Java applet code:

```
/** An applet that posts an alert and waits for the alert button to be pressed.
* Version 1 uses http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html
*/

import netscape.javascript.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Bounce extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    JDialog dialog;
    JSObject window;
    String message;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0,0, 400,40);
        g.drawString(message,40,20);
    }

    public void init() {
        JFrame frame= null;
        dialog= new JDialog(frame, "Bounce App");

        JButton setupButton= new JButton("Bounce it back!");
        setupButton.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel contentPane= new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(setupButton);
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        dialog.setContentPane(contentPane);

        dialog.setSize(new Dimension(400, 110));
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        message= "This applet posts an alert panel.";
        window= JSObject.getWindow(this);
//      String[] params= { "An alert message" };
//      window.call("alert", params);
//      window.eval("alert('Important Alert!')");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        dialog.dispose();
        System.err.println("button has been pushed; focus set");
        message= "Somebody pushed my bounce-back button."; 
        JSObject document= (JSObject)window.getMember("document");
        document.setMember("bgColor", "orange");
        window.eval("focus()");
        repaint();
    }

}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>The Reappearing Page</TITLE></HEAD>
    <body bgcolor="#f0ffc0">

    <H2>Make this page reappear</H2>
    This page will start an applet (white box below) that sets up an alert.
    Before you respond to the alert, hide the window you are reading right now,
    using one of these methods:<ul>
    <li> cover it with another window, </li>
    <li> Hide it using a menu item, </li>
    <li> Minimize it, or </li>
    <li> move it to another workspace or desktop. </li>
    </ul>
    Then click on the button in the alert. 

    <P>
    <EMBED type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.3" width="400" height="40" 
        align="baseline" code="Bounce.class" MAYSCRIPT=true
       pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/plugin-install.html">
    <NOEMBED>
       No JDK 1.3 support for APPLET!!
    </NOEMBED>
    </EMBED>

    <P>What is supposed to happen is that the main window 
    will emerge from wherever you hid it and reappear.
    Since I don't know how to do this, it is your challenge to actually make it happen.
    We need to be able to achieve this magic from any of the situations listed above.</P>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Changed from comment to answer so I can post a decent code snippet for you) There is no reliable way to "foreground" a window using JavaScript, unless it's a window you created yourself from a parent page, for obvious reasons ("Congratulations!! You are our 1000th customer, you win a prize!!!!!"). If you've loaded your applet window as a popup using window.open from another window, you could try using window.focus:

```
var w = window.open(appletPageUrl);
w.focus()
```

I imagine popup blockers don't appreciate this sort of thing, so YMMV. On a personal note, I would suggest that you have a think about whether a user wants to know about your alert if they've chosen to hide/minimise your app.